# How to change proxy IP of selenium webdriver dynamically？Like some js plugins

Tags: selenium

Some js plugins can indeed do. How?

```js
  js_code = f"""
            var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
            prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.type", 1);
            prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.http", "${host}");
            prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.http_port", "${port}");
            prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.ssl", "${host}");
            prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.ssl_port", "${port}");
            prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.ftp", "${host}");
            prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.ftp_port", "${port}");   
            """
```

It is not effict。

Answer (score 0):

I have a more hardcore approach, provided you don't use Headless mode.  And they don't care about the speed.  You can load a fully fledged proxy plug-in before instantiating WebDriver.  LIke SwitchyOmega, when SwitchyOmage is first started, you can choose to go to the second window, and this window is the configuration page of SwitchyOmage, and set its proxy.  Then selenium gets the url of the configuration page, closes the tag, and manually launches the plug-in (because Selenium doesn't control it), but later when you want to change the proxy, you can use Selenium to execute JS to open a new tag and go to the URL of the configuration page.  Change the proxy IP and port number using selenium control elements.  Hahaha, very hardcore!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).